# Performance of the animation with overflow:hidden;

Tags: html, css, performance, animation, css-animations

Let's assume, we have got the following constructs:

Construct A:

```
<div> 
  <A LOT OF CONTENT with images, multiple divs> 
</div>
```

Construct B:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; height;100px"> 
  <A LOT OF CONTENT with images, multiple divs> 
</div>
```

If we now animate both containers:

Does version B have the better overall performance because the browser only has to render a part of the elements? Or does the browser not care and render/repaint everything inside the container anyway?

Comment: It's quite possible this differs between browsers.

Comment: Is this a fact or is that an assumption? Could you give me a few examples? Thank you very much for the answer!